# Wikipedia pseudo code is unclear about how to pad SHA-512

Tags: hash, implementation, sha-1, sha-512

In Wikipedia pseudo code of SHA-512 the padding section says pad 1 bit then 0 bits. It then goes on to say append length without 1 or 0 padding. What does that mean?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Pseudocode

> append length of message (without the '1' bit or padding), in bits, as 64-bit big-endian integer

The appending of message length in sha-2 as a 64 bit integer without 1 and 0 padding is a bit confusing. How is it different from SHA-1?

Comment: it means don't also pad the length like you pad the message, with a "1" at the end

Comment: Related: [SHA256: Padding a 512 bits length message](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29848/sha256-padding-a-512-bits-length-message)

Comment: That remark tells you that you should not consider the padding when computing the length.

Answer (score 1):

Richie is of course correct; the padding needs to be done to form a final block that can also contain the length. As the length encoding is itself static in size, there is no need to pad the length itself.

This is the same as SHA-1 except that the size of the various elements (block size, length encoding) differs.

Comment: Note: SHA-512 use a 128-bit field for the length, when SHA-256 and SHA-1 use a 64-bit field for the length.